# Set Up Access Point Using Wifi

Tags: wireless-access-point

I have seen tutorials on setting up an access point by hard wiring it, but is it possible to set up an access point through wifi?

Can you configure an access point to wirelessly connect back to the "main" router, and use router B as an access point to extend signal?

Comment: That's what a WiFi Range Extender is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check to see if the routers/access points support [WDS (Wireless Distribution System)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system).  But, be aware that throughput is generally cut in half when you do this.

There are other options that don't require running both devices on the same channel like WDS does (which is blamed for most of the throughput hit - [overlapping channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) always causes throughput problems), but my experience has always been that throughput suffers greatly with any of these "extender" type situations.

If you have the time/resources, it's always going to be better to run a wire to the second access point (and make sure it runs on a different channel).